# Use of JPEGImageDecoder on Android platform

Tags: java, android, jpeg, sun

I'm trying to use JPEGImageDecoder interface on my android application, but my application stops unexpectedly. the following code snippet:

```
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageDecoder;

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
JPEGImageDecoder decoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(in);
```

Why my application stops unexpectedly or Can I use these packages on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can use those packages on android. Android uses [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) (android.graphics.BitmapFactory) to handle image decoding. What does the stack trace show?

Comment: yes, you are right. i can't use all java libraries in android. so app stops to work. how can i trace errors or exceptions in eclipse during execution? but when i compile Starting activity com.example.compare.HelloAndroid on device emulator-5554 works fine

Comment: You can use the [adb tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) or the [DDMS tool in eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)